# Ubuntu 16.04, Dell R320 & preseed install via "The Foreman"

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge, foreman, preseed

After lots of trial & error I've finally given up on the "SATA RAID" the R320 provides, and resorted to using AHCI mode.

Partitioning/Provisioning work fine, but on the next boot the machine claims to have no OS.

Booting it in rescue mode of an ISO (vFlash) I can mount the disks, chroot to the installed OS, re-install GRUB w/o errors, but it still won't boot afterwards.

Running a complete install of the ISO works as expected.

How do I identify the cause of this behaviour, and, more importantly, make it go away?

[edit 1 below]

So I tried taking the selections from the manual install, filtered out anything that had disk|partm|grub and created a preseed partitioning file for the R320 from that; using that the machine never gets past `partman: reading all physical volumes` ...

[edit 2 below]

So .. not being able to find out why/how the provisioned system is never bootable with 16.04 I figured I'd try debian8 (Jessie) and ask them about preseed in IRC when it fails.  Added Debian as an OS in foreman, associated it with the same preseed files as Ubuntu, changed the hosts OS from Ubuntu 16.06 to Debian, kicked off a build.  Had to answer 2 installer questions (language, hdd for grub), and had a working server in about 30 minutes :/  Not what I was going for.  Can anyone tell me how to find out why Ubuntu behaves so differently?

Cheers